# How can I call a sequence of functions until the return value meets some condition?

Tags: python, design-patterns

Sometimes I find myself writing code like this:

```
def analyse(somedata):
    result = bestapproach(somedata)
    if result:
        return result
    else:
        result = notasgood(somedata)
        if result:
            return result
        else:
            result = betterthannothing(somedata)
            if result:
                return result
            else:
                return None
```

That's pretty ugly. Of course, some people like to leave off some of that syntax:

```
def analyse(somedata):
    result = bestapproach(somedata)
    if result:
        return result
    result = notasgood(somedata)
    if result:
        return result
    result = betterthannothing(somedata)
    if result:
        return result
```

But that's not much of an improvement; there's still a ton of duplicated code here, and it's still ugly.

I looked into using the built-in `iter()` with a sentinel value, but in this case the `None` value is being used to signal that the loop should keep going, as opposed to a sentinel which is used to signal that the loop should terminate.

Are there any other (sane) techniques in Python for implementing this sort of "keep trying until you find something that works" pattern?

I should clarify that "return value meets some condition" is not limited to cases where the condition is `if bool(result) is True` as in the example. It could be that the list of possible analysis functions each produce some coefficient measuring the degree of success (e.g. an R-squared value), and you want to set a minimum threshold for acceptance. Therefore, a *general* solution should not inherently rely on the truth value of the result.

Comment: I'm not a python guy, but got here via the design pattern tag. Your structure looks like a [Recovery Block](http://books.google.ca/books?id=jZgSAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA4-IA1&ots=VMMxfkzdQ2&dq=software%20%22recovery%20block%22%20ensure&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q=software%20%22recovery%20block%22%20ensure&f=false). If you know the fault-tolerant pattern, there's nothing wrong with that code. I'd argue the other answers even make it less readable. Repeating code is not a bad thing sometimes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Option #1: Using `or`

When the number of total functions is a) known, and b) small, and the test condition is based entirely on the truth value of the return, it's possible to simply use `or` as Grapsus suggested:

```
d = 'somedata'
result = f1(d) or f2(d) or f3(d) or f4(d)
```

Because [Python's boolean operators short-circuit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), the functions are executed from right to left until one of them produces a return value evaluated as `True`, at which point the assignment is made to `result` and the remaining functions are not evaluated; or until you run out of functions, and `result` is assigned `False`.

---

### Option #2: Using generators

When the number of total functions is a) unknown, or b) very large, a one-liner generator comprehension method works, as Bitwise suggested:

```
result = (r for r in (f(somedata) for f in functions) if <test-condition>).next()
```

This has the additional advantage over option #1 that you can use any `<test-condition>` you wish, instead of relying only on truth value. Each time `.next()` is called:

1. We ask the outer generator for its next element
2. The outer generator asks the inner generator for its next element
3. The inner generator asks for an `f` from `functions` and tries to evaluate `f(somedata)`
4. If the expression can be evaluated (i.e., `f` is a function and `somedata` is a valid arugment), the inner generator yields the return value of `f(somedata)` to the outer generator
5. If `<test-condition>` is satisfied, the outer generator yields the return value of `f(somedata)` and we assign it as `result`
6. If `<test-condition>` was not satisfied in step 5, repeat steps 2-4

A weakness of this method is that nested comprehensions can be less intuitive than their multi-line equivalents. Also, if the inner generator is exhausted without ever satisfying the test condition, `.next()` raises a `StopIteration` which must be handled (in a try-except block) or prevented (by ensuring the last function will always "succeed").

---

### Option #3: Using a custom function

Since we can place callable functions in a list, one option is to explicitly list the functions you want to "try" in the order they should be used, and then iterate through that list:

```
def analyse(somedata):
    analysis_functions = [best, okay, poor]
    for f in analysis_functions:
        result = f(somedata)
        if result:
            return result
```

Advantages: Fixes the problem of repeated code, it's more clear that you're engaged in an iterative process, and it short-circuits (doesn't continue executing functions after it finds a "good" result).

This could also be written with Python's `for ... else` syntax:*

```
def analyse(somedata):
    analysis_functions = [best, okay, poor]
    for f in analysis_functions:
        result = f(somedata)
        if result:
            break
    else:
        return None
    return result
```

The advantage here is that the different ways to exit the function are identified, which could be useful if you want complete failure of the `analyse()` function to return something other than `None`, or to raise an exception. Otherwise, it's just longer and more esoteric.

*As described in ["Transforming Code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python"](http://pyvideo.org/video/1780), starting @15:50.

Answer (score 6):

If the number of functions is not too high, why not use the `or` operator ?

```
d = 'somedata'
result = f1(d) or f2(d) or f3(d) or f4(d)
```

It will only apply the functions until one of them returns something not `False`.

Comment: I also think that it's easier to understand than `map`, `filter` etc soup.

Comment: This would be a good approach if you literally are doing `if result`, but that may have been shorthand.

Comment: Won't this fail on zero?

Comment: I like it. However, if the expected results can contain anything that would *evaluate* to `False`, like `0` or the empty list `[]`, this won't work.

Comment: `0` or anything else evaluating to `False` will fail but it would also fail in OP's example. The solution is either making sure the functions return False-like stuff only when appropriate or writing a small validation routine to wrap the calls to the functions. This would be necessary with the `filter` solution too.

Comment: There are certainly cases where you might want to use a more involved test than `if result`; for example, perhaps you're trying several different regression approaches and returning an R-squared value, and you want to return the first result that exceeds a minimum threshold for acceptance. That being said, this is nice and succinct, in the cases where it works. +1

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty pythonic:

```
result = (i for i in (f(somedata) for f in funcs) if i is not None).next()
```

The idea is to use generators so you do lazy evaluation instead of evaluating all functions. Note that you can change the `condition`/`funcs` to be whatever you like, so this is more robust than the `or` solution proposed by Grapsus.

This is a good example why generators are powerful in Python.

**A more detailed description of how this works:**

We ask this generator for a single element. The outer generator then asks the inner generator `(f(d) for f in funcs)` for a single element, and evaluates it. If it passes the condition then we are done and it exits, otherwise it continues asking the inner generator for elements.

Comment: Hmm, I would have guessed that nesting the generators would exhaust the inner one, but I tested it and you're right about the lazy evaluation. (also: how about `i is not None`)